# Class Mailchimp does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

I've just added the MailChimp extension in Magento 2.2.5. But there is a configuration error occurring. When I click on the configuration of MailChimp it doesn't show anything and store configuration throwing an error message

> "Class Mailchimp does not exist"

. Can anybody help me out of this issue?

Comment: i think u need to include mailchmip files in your script.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed same issue with composer command.

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

You can also download zip folder of library.

https://api.github.com/repos/ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib/zipball/293960203ff1d834af5b2f2726f03063494a2265

Comment: where to place src folder, please guide

Answer (score 0):

- Suggestion 1 : ensure you've [**followed the documentation**](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/#install+mailchimp+for+magento+2)

  - Suggestion 2: restart PHP

    - Suggestion 3: Check that your Mailchimp class is the correct name/location for autoloading. Or otherwise ensure that the mailchimp class is loaded manually.

      - Suggestion 4: Check namespacing.

        - Suggestion 5: ensure you've [**followed the documentation**](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/#install+mailchimp+for+magento+2)

          - Suggestion 6: Check out the [Mailchimp GitHub issues and documentation](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/issues).